# How to test Windows Service Account can login to SQL Server database?

Tags: windows, active-directory, sql-server, windows-authentication, service-accounts

How to test that a Windows AD service account has been granted access to read from a SQL Server database server via Windows Authentication ?

This would need be an isolated test independent of any operations running within the Windows Service.

Comment: I'm failing to understand the question... why not just login with the service account and test it?  Add some detail here to describe what you are trying to do, and why it is special or unique that requires asking for help at all.

Comment: It's not always possible or practical to interactively login as service account.  What if the service account password is not known or managed by the system ?  What if it's not convenient to logout from working session and login as service account ?

Answer (score 2):

From PowerShell:

```
Import-Module SqlServer
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "DBSERVER.COMPANY.COM" -Query "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DBName.dbo.TableOrViewName;"
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, your PS is not executing under the context of the service account.  Are you implying that I can somehow login to PS as the service account ?

Comment: @BaltoStar: *Windows Authentication* means it will authenticate with the credentials that the script is executed under. Specifying the credentials (username/password) for the service account is possible, but that isn't Windows Auth.  "If Username and Password are not specified, this cmdlet attempts a Windows Authentication connection using the Windows account running the Windows PowerShell session. When possible, use Windows Authentication." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Answer (score 1):

Shift-Right-Click on the icon for your favorite tool of choice (or command prompt, PowerShell, etc.) and select "Run as a different user".  Enter the service account credentials, login as usual, execute a representative query.

The same thing can be done from command line using the runas command:

```
RUNAS /noprofile /netonly /user:<service account> <program>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for example possible with [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) on the SQL server.

With this tool you'd be able to set filters so that only the desired transactions will be shown.

It will show among other things: Source Host, Source Program (your Service), Account, Destination DB of a login or transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for a simple way to directly test authentication & authorization : login + select * from db1.dbo.table1